# Calculate the date after X days with a user input date

Tags: c, date, date-arithmetic

First and foremost, I am new so I am sorry for any incorrect terms I use for explaining. While I do speak English quite well I don't learn C in English,so I'll do my best to translate and understand correctly.
I am trying to write a program where the program asks a user to input a date (0<= year <=9999) and the programs then validates if that is a logical date (including leap years). if it's not logical the program asks to input a date again, until it is. When it's a logical date the program then prints it and asks the user to input a number (-1000000 <= N <= 1000000) of days and then print the date after\before the N amount of days.
I have the Date code pretty much set up,though I can't seem to get the while loop to return to the beginning when the date is wrong.
I also am trying to figure out a an algorithm to calculate the date after\before N days.
sorry for going on so long and thank you for all helpers/insights.FYI because this is a first assignment I am not allowed to use arrays or strings, so I understand the code will be bulky

---

```
void main()
{//d=day m=month y=year
    int dd, mm, yy, flag = 0;
    printf("Enter day month and year:\n");
    scanf("%d\n%d\n%d", &dd, &mm, &yy);
    //year check
    while (flag==0)
    {
        if (yy >= 0 && yy <= 9999 && mm >= 1 && mm <= 12 && dd >= 1 && dd <= 31);
        {
            //month check
            if (mm >= 1 && mm <= 12);
            {
                //day check
                if ((dd >= 1 && dd <= 31) && (mm == 1 || mm == 3 || mm == 5 || mm == 7 || mm == 8 || mm == 10 || mm == 12))
                    printf("\n%d\n%d\n%d", dd, mm, yy);
                else
                    if ((dd >= 1 && dd <= 30) && (mm == 34 || mm == 6 || mm == 9 || mm == 1))
                        printf("\n%d\n%d\n%d", dd, mm, yy);
                //leap year check
                if ((dd >= 1 && dd <= 28) && mm == 2)
                    printf("\n%d\n%d\n%d", dd, mm, yy);
                else
                    if ((dd == 29) && mm == 2 && (yy % 400 == 0 || yy % 100 != 0 && yy % 4 == 0))
                        printf("\n%d\n%d\n%d", dd, mm, yy);
            }
        } 
    }(flag = 1);

}
```

---

Comment: Assuming that you want the 'flag' to indicate 'valid_date' (may be renamed the flag to 'valid_date'). So the while should be `while (flag == 0)`. Then set the flag to 1, when you recognized a valid date. Also, take '{ flag = 1}' at the end of the while - other code will not compile. This will get you thru the first step (getting valid date)

Comment: for some reason i didn't type the 0 after the flag so thank you for pointing it out!
I'm not quite sure what you mean by renaming the flag

Comment: Can you use `mktime()` and `localtime()`?  Can you code functions for this assignment?

Comment: "I am not allowed to use arrays or strings" is violated with 3 _string literals_ which are arrays/strings: `"Enter day month and year:\n"`, `"%d\n%d\n%d"` and `"\n%d\n%d\n%d"`.

Comment: I'm sorry maybe strings is not the correct translation...and I am not familiar with mktime and localtime so I guess not.